# CADMapper DXF into Blender 2.79

Tags: import

I'm attempting to import .DXF files into Blender that were created via CadMapper. I have the import/export add-ons, however when I import the file I get a host of error messages and can not see the file/render. I'm assuming there are specific import settings I need to configure prior to import, but any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Can you post pictures of the errors, or a log of the errors, or a link to the plugin you are using, or all the above?

Answer (score 1):

The Blender DXF importer does not work well for 3d objects. I would suggest that you either download a sketchup file and convert it into a format that Blender can import or alternatively, use the [Blender-OSM addon](https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm). Info should be exactly the same as Cadmapper also uses OSM data.